# How would you access the underlying array passed to a function expecting an empty interface in Go?

Tags: pointers, types, interface, go

So let's say that we have a function of the following form:

```
func WorkMagic(obj interface{}) interface{} {
    switch t := obj.(type) { 
    case string:
        // Do string magic
    default:
        // Do slice magic
    }
    ...
}
```

I am expecting `obj` to be either a string or a slice, which I can ascertain via the switch. In the case of a slice, I want to be able to do ordering work on any arbitrary slice, regardless of type. Seems like the best way to accomplish this is using the unsafe package in a similar fashion to that discussed in [this article](http://www.goinggo.net/2013/07/understanding-pointers-and-memory.html).

Here however, the function accepts a specific type of slice (`[]string`), whereas I would like to be able to work on any slice. So the question is, given that I am accepting an empty interface as input, how might I access the underlying slice / array using unsafe.Pointer so as to be able to loop through and modify which value is associate with which index?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an actual interface instead of `interface{}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use [reflection](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). It enables you to work generically without giving up type and memory safety like `unsafe` would. Read the Go blog's [Laws of Reflection](http://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).

```
func actOnSlices(i interface{}) {

    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

    for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr { // dereference pointers
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    if v.Kind() != reflect.Slice { // ensure you actually got a slice
        panic("given argument is not a slice")
    }

    // do slice stuff

}
```

Edit to answer your second question:

Yes – this can be done: elements of a slice are adressable and hence settable. See the [following working example](http://play.golang.org/p/TJ1Ov5L2J1):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    s := []string{"foo", "bar"}
    fmt.Println(swapIndexes(s, 0, 1)) // prints [bar foo]
}

func swapIndexes(i interface{}, x, y int) interface{} {

    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

    for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr { // dereference pointers
        v = v.Elem()
    }

    if v.Kind() != reflect.Slice { // ensure you actually got a slice
        panic("given argument is not a slice")
    }

    t := v.Index(x).Interface()

    v.Index(x).Set(v.Index(y))

    v.Index(y).Set(reflect.ValueOf(t))

    return v.Interface()

}
```

Edit to answer your third question:

The `unsafe` package is not something you'll encounter much in user-land code. It exists to implement certain features (e.g. reflection, C interaction) that need to circumvent Go's safety guarantees to work. Using `unsafe` is unsafe, as the name suggests, because you can mess up big time without even realizing. By using `unsafe`, you're incurring in a big trade-off, so it better be worth it. Quoting @twotwotwo:

> The downside of unsafe is that if you mess up you're in the old days of segfaults, memory corruption, and buffer-overflow security holes.

Also, as @twotwotwo suggested; it's more "Go-like" to repeat code than using reflection to achieve genericity.

To Go's type-system, `[]string` and `[]int` are two completely separate and unrelated types. just as `int` and `string` would be. The relation (both are slices) is obvious only to the programmer. There is no way of expressing "a slice" without saying a slice of *what*.

Comment: Problem with this is that reflect.ValueOf returns a reflect.Value, which is not a slice and is not settable for slices. So, for example, if I wanted to to exchange the arbitrarily typed first and second values of any slice, not sure how I would do this. But if I used pointers, could theoretically just swap the pointers. So how would you do this using your method?

Comment: the elements of a `reflect.Value` of a slice are settable; I have edited the answer.

Comment: Hm. That does do just what I was after. Just so complicated using reflect. To follow up on something you said above. You mention memory safety. Clearly there are instances where the unsafe package is needed or it wouldn't be included. When would such a solution be called for and what are the dangers of using such a solution here? Seems like this is pretty self-contained, so I'm not understanding why using unsafe would be frowned upon. Appreciate the clarifications.

Comment: If you can get by withoug trying to buld generic stuff like this (e.g., if you can just write loops instead of map()), that's encouraged. The downside of `unsafe` is that if you mess up you're in the old days of segfaults, memory corruption, and buffer-overflow security holes.